# How to make my Console.ReadLine() stop returning my backspace inputs?

Tags: c#

First and foremost, I feel it necessary to mention that I am currently using replit for this program. The issue that I am currently having with my code is that it runs perfectly, the only issue is that when I try to backspace using the methods listed below and fix a number or letter that I have mistyped in my input while running the program, I get an error saying that the value must be positive and below the buffer height. I realized that the issue is some of my `Console.ReadLine();` placements. They are causing my program to read backspace as an input and in turn, I am receiving an error because backspace is neither a letter or number input. Is there any way that I can move them around without having to rewrite the whole method line?

```
public static void AddItemToStore() {
              Console.WriteLine("========= Adding Item to Store =========");
              Console.WriteLine();
              Console.WriteLine("You will need to enter an item description, price, and quantity on hand.");
              Console.WriteLine();
              Console.WriteLine("Please enter an item description:");
              string input = Console.ReadLine();
              
              double entry = GetPrice();
              int value = GetQuantity();
              itemDescription.Add(input);
              itemPrice.Add(Convert.ToDouble(entry));
              itemQoh.Add(value);
              SaveData();
            }
public static string GetCustomerName() {
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("=========== List of Customers =========== ");
      Console.WriteLine();
      for (int i = 0; i < salesCustomerName.Count; i++) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}. {salesCustomerName[i]} ");
        Console.WriteLine();
      }
      while (true) {
        Console.WriteLine("Please choose a Customer name:");
        Console.WriteLine();
        return Console.ReadLine();
         }
      }
public static double GetPrice() {
      while (true) {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the price of the item (x.xx):");
        string entry = Console.ReadLine();
        double value;
        if (!double.TryParse(entry, out value) || value <= 0){
          Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid price value.");
        } else {
        return Convert.ToDouble(entry);
        }
      }
    }
 public static int GetQuantity() {
      while (true){
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the item quantity:");
        string entry = Console.ReadLine();
       int value = 0;

        if (Int32.TryParse(entry, out value) && Convert.ToInt32(entry) > 0){
          return Convert.ToInt32(entry);
        }
        else{
          Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid value.");
        }
      }
    }
```

Listed above are the methods that I am currently having an issue with. They work perfectly with inputting information but as soon as I press backspace, I get an error. Down below I will have my whole program listed as well.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

class Program {

    public static List<string> itemDescription = new List<string>();
    public static List<double> itemPrice = new List<double>();
    public static List<int> itemQoh = new List<int>();
    public static List<string> customerName = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> salesCustomerName = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> salesItemDescription = new List<string>();
    public static List<double> salesItemPrice = new List<double>();
    public static List<int> salesQuantity = new List<int>();

    public static void Main (string[] args) {
      ReadData();
      bool keepGoing = true;
      while (keepGoing) {
        string entry = GetMenuOption();
        if (entry.ToLower() == "q"){
        Console.WriteLine("Thanks for shopping with us! Come back soon! :)");  
        }
        switch (entry) {
          case "1":
            GoShopping();
            break;
          case "2":
            Management();
            break;
          case "Q":
            keepGoing = false;
            break;
        }
      }
    } 
    
    public static void AddItemToStore() {
      Console.WriteLine("========= Adding Item to Store =========");
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("You will need to enter an item description, price, and quantity on hand.");
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("Please enter an item description:");
      string input = Console.ReadLine();
      
      double entry = GetPrice();
      int value = GetQuantity();
      itemDescription.Add(input);
      itemPrice.Add(Convert.ToDouble(entry));
      itemQoh.Add(value);
      SaveData();
    }
  
    public static void AddItemToCart(string name, int item) {
        Console.WriteLine();
         Console.WriteLine($"There are {itemQoh[item]} {itemDescription[item]} available for {itemPrice[item]:C2} each.");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please choose the amount of items that you would like to purchase");
        string val = Console.ReadLine();
        int pur_qty =0;
        int num = -1;
        if (!int.TryParse(val, out num)) {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid integer");
        } else {
           pur_qty = Convert.ToInt32(val);
        
          if (pur_qty <= itemQoh[item]  ){

            itemQoh[item] = itemQoh[item]-pur_qty;
            salesCustomerName.Add(name);
            salesItemDescription.Add(itemDescription[item]);
            salesItemPrice.Add(itemPrice[item]);
            salesQuantity.Add(pur_qty);
            SaveData();
          }else{
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid value");
          }
        }
    }
    
    public static void ChangePrice() {
      Console.WriteLine("========= Changing Price =========");
      int entry = Convert.ToInt32(GetItemNumber());
      int price = 0;
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine($"Updating price. {itemDescription[price]} currently costs {itemPrice[price]:C2}.");
      double new_price = GetPrice();
      itemPrice[entry]= new_price;
      SaveItems();
      SaveData();
    }

    public static void ChangeQoh() {
      Console.WriteLine("========= Changing Quantity =========");
      int entry = Convert.ToInt32(GetItemNumber());
      int value = 0;
      Console.WriteLine($"Updating quantity. There are currently {itemQoh[value]} {itemDescription[value]} available.");
      Console.WriteLine();
      int new_qty = GetQuantity();
      itemQoh[entry]=new_qty;
      SaveItems();
      SaveData();
    }

    public static string GetCustomerName() {
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("=========== List of Customers =========== ");
      Console.WriteLine();
      for (int i = 0; i < salesCustomerName.Count; i++) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}. {salesCustomerName[i]} ");
        Console.WriteLine();
      }
      while (true) {
        Console.WriteLine("Please choose a Customer name:");
        Console.WriteLine();
        return Console.ReadLine();
         }
      }
    

    public static int GetItemNumber() {
      ListAllItems();
      int counter = itemDescription.Count;
      string number;
      int item = 1;
      bool keepGoing = true;
      while (keepGoing){
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter an item number:");
        number = Console.ReadLine();
        item = Convert.ToInt32(number);
        if (item < 1 || item > counter) {
          Console.WriteLine();
          Console.WriteLine($"Please enter a valid item number between 1 and {counter}.");
          Console.WriteLine();
          
        } else {
          keepGoing = false;
      }
    }
    return item -1;
    }

    public static string GetMenuOption() {
      Console.WriteLine("=========== Main Menu ===========");
      Console.WriteLine("1. Go Shopping");
      Console.WriteLine("2. Management Menu");
      Console.WriteLine("Q. Quit the program");
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.Write("Please enter your choice: ");
      return Console.ReadLine();
    }
    
    public static string GetManagementMenuOption() {
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("=========== Management Menu =====");
      Console.WriteLine("1. Browse sales receipts");
      Console.WriteLine("2. View all items");
      Console.WriteLine("3. Add an item");
      Console.WriteLine("4. Change Quantity of Items on Hand");
      Console.WriteLine("5. Change Prices of Items");
      Console.WriteLine("Q. Return to Main Menu");
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.Write("Please enter your choice: ");
      return Console.ReadLine();
    }
    
    public static double GetPrice() {
      while (true) {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the price of the item (x.xx):");
        string entry = Console.ReadLine();
        double value;
        if (!double.TryParse(entry, out value) || value <= 0){
          Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid price value.");
        } else {
        return Convert.ToDouble(entry);
        }
      }
    }
    
    public static string GetShoppingOption() {
     
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("=========== Shopping Menu ===========");
      Console.WriteLine("1. Choose an item");
      Console.WriteLine("Q. Checkout");
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.Write("Please enter your choice: ");
      return Console.ReadLine();
    }
    
    public static int GetQuantity() {
      while (true){
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the item quantity:");
        string entry = Console.ReadLine();
       int value = 0;

        if (Int32.TryParse(entry, out value) && Convert.ToInt32(entry) > 0){
          return Convert.ToInt32(entry);
        }
        else{
          Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid value.");
        }
      }
    }

    
    private static void GoShopping() {
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("Please enter the name of the shopper:");      
      while (true) {
      string name = Console.ReadLine();
        string entry = GetShoppingOption();
        switch (entry) {
          case "1" :              
            int item = GetItemNumber();
            if (item != -1) {          
            AddItemToCart(name, item);
            SaveData(); 
            }
            break;
          case "Q" :
            PrintTotalCart(name);
          return;
        }
      }
    }

    public static void ListAllItems() {
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("============== All Items ============= ");
      for (int i = 0; i < itemDescription.Count; i++) {
        Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}. {itemDescription[i]} costs {itemPrice[i]:C2}. There are {itemQoh[i]} available.");
        Console.WriteLine();
      }
    }

    
    public static void Management() {
      while (true) {
          string entry = GetManagementMenuOption();
          if (entry.ToLower() == "q") {
            return;
          } else {
            switch (entry) {
              case "1" : 
                string customer = GetCustomerName();
                PrintTotalCart(customer);
                break;
              case "2" :
                ListAllItems();
                break;
              case "3" :
                AddItemToStore();
                break;
              case "4" :
                ChangeQoh();
                break;
              case "5" :
                ChangePrice();
                break;
              default:
                Console.WriteLine("Please make a valid selection");
                break;
            }
          }
        }
    }

    public static void PrintTotalCart(string name) {
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine($"======= All Purchases for  {name} =======" );
      
      double total_cost= 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < salesCustomerName.Count; i++) {
        if(salesCustomerName[i] == name) {
              total_cost += salesQuantity[i] *salesItemPrice[i];
          Console.WriteLine($"{salesQuantity[i]} {salesItemDescription[i]} at the price of {salesItemPrice[i]:C2} each for a total of {salesQuantity[i] *salesItemPrice[i]:C2}.");
        }
      }
        Console.WriteLine();
          Console.WriteLine($"Total cost of the cart for {name} is {total_cost:C2}.");
    }
    public static void ReadData() {
      ReadItems();
      ReadSales();
    }

    public static void ReadItems() {
      var filename = "items.csv";
      if (File.Exists(filename)) {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename)) {
          reader.ReadLine();
          while (!reader.EndOfStream) {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(",");
            itemDescription.Add(values[0]);
            itemPrice.Add(Convert.ToDouble(values[1]));
            itemQoh.Add(Convert.ToInt32(values[2]));
          }
        }
      }else {
      Console.WriteLine($"{filename} not found");
     }
    
    }

    public static void ReadSales() {
      var filename = "sales.csv";
      if (File.Exists(filename)) {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename)) {
          reader.ReadLine();
          while (!reader.EndOfStream) {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(",");
            salesCustomerName.Add(values[0]);
            salesItemDescription.Add(values[1]);
            salesItemPrice.Add(Convert.ToDouble(values[2]));
            salesQuantity.Add(Convert.ToInt32(values[3]));
          }
        }
      }else {
      Console.WriteLine($"{filename} not found");
     }
    
    }

    public static void SaveData() {
      SaveItems();
      SaveSales();
    }

    public static void SaveItems() {
      string filename = "items.csv";
      using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename)) {
        writer.WriteLine("Item_Description,Item_Price,Qoh");
        for (int i = 0; i < itemDescription.Count; i++) {
          writer.WriteLine($"{itemDescription[i]},{itemPrice[i]},{itemQoh[i]}");
      }
     }
    }
    
    public static void SaveSales() {
      string filename = "sales.csv";
      using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename)) {
        writer.WriteLine("Customer_Name,Item_Description,Item_Price,Sales_Qty");
        for (int i = 0; i < salesCustomerName.Count; i++) {
          writer.WriteLine($"{salesCustomerName[i]},{salesItemDescription[i]},{salesItemPrice[i]},{salesQuantity[i]}");
      }
     }
     
    }
    }
```

[image]

This is the error that I receive each time that I enter the backspace.

Comment: _in certain areas_ what areas? Should we try to debug your program on the fly? Please post an [MCVE]

Comment: I have edited my OG post so that it will help. Also I wish that I could minimize the program but the lines that I am having issues with call to other lines in my program as well as my program being menu driven and using a CSV. I am a first time programmer so I am having a rough time with this. I apologize for not  being having the knowledge of how to simplify my program.

Comment: Does this error happen _every_ time you hit backspace? Or does it happen at a certain point when running your app? I ask because I am running your code and I haven't been able to replicate this error you are getting...

Comment: Backspace wouldn't normally conflict with ReadLine as far as I know. Do you have repro steps to get this error?

Comment: Works fine here, no issues when using backspace.

Comment: When I run my program and I go into the management menu and I go into my change quantity on hand option, after I enter the item number and it asks me to input the item quantity, if I click backspace, the whole program just crashes. The same happens when I use the change item price option as well as Browse sales receipts options.  I believe that it might just be a replit problem though if you aren't having the same issues. I have added a picture of what error is appearing for me.

Comment: I believe so too. In a console project in Visual Studio it works fine

Comment: Typically when a .NET program "crashes" an unhandled exception is thrown. You can use a debugger to break your program when it happens or catch the exception before your application exits. Both methods will allow you to inspect the exception to better understand your problem.

Comment: @Daniel pretty sure it is a Replit issue. I can't think of anything else, and was still unable to replicate the error after trying what you said. Anyway, one thing you could try is messing around with the `Console.BufferHeight` value and see if that makes any difference. Just an idea